# Solaris11 second network works fine with virtualbox..but not with vnic

Tags: networking, virtualbox, solaris

I need a second network for testing.
Ok, I can use another mask for enlarge number of hosts,but I don' like
I want a

```
192.168.0.0/24 home
```

and

```
10.2.0.0/24 testing
```

The testing network is for virtual machines(virtualbox)
running on solaris11 host.
So i create a vnic linked to net0

```
dladm create-vnic -l net0 vnic1
```

Create the ip

```
ipadm create-ip vnic1
ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.2.0.1 vnic1/v4
```

And then I simply attach the Virtualbox virtualnetwork
to briged adapter(selecting vnic1) and wow...nothing work.
I cannot ping the vm's from home network even configuring
correctly the route.
So I delete the vnic..and I recreate all using a second(physical)
network adapter,called net1 on server.

```
 ipadm create-ip net1
 ipadm create-addr -T static -a 10.2.0.1 net1/v4
```

And then I simply attach the Virtualbox virtualnetwork
to briged adapter(selecting net1) and wow..this times works.
I can ping the vm's from solaris and from my home network.
The simply question is: why with vnic not?Is a limit of Solaris or VirtualBox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well ... it's neither really a limit of Solaris or a limit of Virtualbox but a consequence how everything in this regards works. A vnic has it's own ARP address but the networking logic of virtualbox doesn't know about it. There is a trick however to get this running as a workaround. Allow promiscous mode for the VM on the interface in Virtualbox and start a tcpdump on the system in that VM ... then the VNIC configuration should work.